# Rails 4, RSpec Application has been already initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been trying to use RSpec with Rails 4 but came across this error that I can't get rid of.

However, when I run test on single *.rb files it works without any errors. I use guard and have tried to run rspec in single mode but received the same error.

```
13:46:26 - INFO - Running: spec
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize!': Application has been already initialized. (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/xxx/Documents/Mitt_bolag/Minnesota/beställningssite/order_site/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/xxx/Documents/Mitt_bolag/Minnesota/beställningssite/order_site/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/xxx/Documents/Mitt_bolag/Minnesota/beställningssite/order_site/spec/requests/products_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

This is my `spec_helper.rb`

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end

class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

Comment: Please add the command you use to run all tests - `rake spec` or `rake` for example.  :)

Comment: Try removing ` config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller` and see what happends.  Might not fix but might uncover.

Comment: I use guard to run all tests =)

Comment: removing the config.include ... didn't help any I'm afraid, still the same error.

Comment: What happens if you run the tests without guard?

Comment: Same error appears :(

Comment: Have you tried removing the `class ActionController ...` from your spec_helper?

Comment: See my spec_helper below in case that... helps ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your spec_helper to this:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec' # NOTE: I DON'T have this but you do...
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem while upgrading a Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.2 app to Rails 4.2 and Rails 2.6. Apparently, `ActionController::TestResponse` is reused and therefore initialized multiple times. You can add a workaround [reading this thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34790#issuecomment-450502805), or simply create `spec/support/action_controller_workaround.rb`:

```
if RUBY_VERSION>='2.6.0'
  if Rails.version < '5'
    class ActionController::TestResponse < ActionDispatch::TestResponse
      def recycle!
        # hack to avoid MonitorMixin double-initialize error:
        @mon_mutex_owner_object_id = nil
        @mon_mutex = nil
        initialize
      end
    end
  else
    puts "Monkeypatch for ActionController::TestResponse no longer needed"
  end
end
```

Comment: That was exactly my case! Anyway this revised workaround is more efficient https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34790#issuecomment-681034561

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've already got the solution, but here I go anyway:

I'm facing the same problem since yesterday. I've found that running a 
single spec by time or removing the 'require "spec_helper" from all specs but one,
it would work.
And a few minutes ago, I've found that the problem was the ruby version.

If you upgrade your ruby-2.0.0-p0 to ruby-2.0.0-p247, then the problem goes away!

I hope I've been helpful.